# Display Zoom for iOS under settings, display, display zoom

Tags: accessibility

Looking to begin an accessibility vision app for iOS and I’m not having any luck locating properties or code that allows access to the display zoom. Has anyone worked with these areas before?
[Zoom Display Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl5IV.jpg)